# React and MUI - My clicking button animation isn't working like I wanted

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-transitions, jss

I have this Button from MUIv5 and I would like to fully animate it once it's pressed.

The **problem** is I have to hold the button to make the full animation and not just one simple click

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code.

```
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function App() {
  const buttonJSS = {
    ":active": {
      animation: "MoveUpDown 0.3s linear",
      animationFillMode: "forwards"
    },

    "@keyframes MoveUpDown": {
      "0%, 100%": {
        transform: "translateY(0)"
      },
      "50%": {
        transform: "translateY(20px)"
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button sx={buttonJSS}>MY BUTTON</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The link of the codesandbox is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-frog-rim6xw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `:active`, and the time of animation is 0.3 second,
But Button activity time is less than 0.3 second. So the styling is not complete.

You can use `className` toggle to make this animation:

```js
function App() {
    const { Button } = MaterialUI;

    const [active, setActive] = React.useState(false);

    const buttonJSS = {
        "&.active": {
            animation: "MoveUpDown 0.3s linear",
            animationFillMode: "forwards"
        },

        "@keyframes MoveUpDown": {
            "0%, 100%": {
                transform: "translateY(0)"
            },
            "50%": {
                transform: "translateY(20px)"
            }
        }
    };

    const handleClick = () => {
        setActive(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            setActive(false);
        }, 300)
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Button sx={buttonJSS} className={active ? 'active' : ''} onClick={handleClick}>MY BUTTON</Button>
        </div>
    );
  }

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Edit geocoding-demo (forked)]